# Can't get variable value outside task scope Firebase unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm here getting started with Firebase inside Unity. I figured out how to get data from my database. But the problem is that I can't get the value outside of the task that I am creating to get the data.

Here is the function that I am using, so you guys know what I am talking about:

```
    public double GetBankBalance()
{
    double bankBalance = 0;
    Router.PlayerMoney("ymO6Hyl8WjbuPGaWV7FksbVABGb2").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {   
    if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error in GetBankBalance()");
        }
    else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            bankBalance = Convert.ToDouble(snapshot.Child("bankBalance").Value);
        }
        Debug.Log(bankBalance);
        SetBankBalance(bankBalance);
    });
    Debug.Log(bankBalance);
    return bankBalance;
}
```

I'll explain it a bit:

The "Router.PlayerMoney is just the path to the values that I need. The problem here is that inside the task the Debug.Log(bankBalance) returns the correct value but just outside (the Debug.Log above my return) the value is 0 as I gave bankBalance the value at the beginning of the function.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I tried instance variables but that won't work.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Don't know a lot about the library but based on the name of the function GetValueAsync() I would assume the second Debug.Log is executing before the first, due to the asynchronous manner in which you are getting the bank balance.

Comment: By the time your GetValueAsync task finishes - control flow already left GetBankBalance method, because you don't wait for this task to complete.